# sorting SQL with substring on string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i have the data like this:

```
CODE_VD

N_10_19_xxx
N_0_3_xxx
N_121_131_xxx
N_100_120_xxx
N_80_90_xxx
N_20_29_xxx
```

as you can see i need to sort just the first number after N_,i don't know how can i get this number.

i have tried with susbsting(CODE_VD,2,3) but not exactly what i expected.

i want to get this:

```
CODE_VD

N_0_3_xxx
N_10_19_xxx
N_20_29_xxx
N_80_90_xxx
N_100_120_xxx
N_121_131_xxx
```

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    CODE_VD VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( CODE_VD )
VALUES
('N_10_19_xxx'),
('N_0_3_xxx'),
('N_121_131_xxx'),
('N_100_120_xxx'),
('N_80_90_xxx'),
('N_20_29_xxx');

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        CONVERT(INT,
        SUBSTRING(mt.CODE_VD, 
            3, 
            CHARINDEX('_', mt.CODE_VD, 3) - 3)) ConvCol
    FROM @MyTable mt
) mt
ORDER BY mt.ConvCol
```

I converted to int to get the sort to work correctly, because 100 > 20

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CODE_VD,3, CHARINDEX('_',CODE_VD, 3)-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @t Table (CODE_VD VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @t (CODE_VD)VALUES ('N_10_19_xxx')
INSERT INTO @t (CODE_VD)VALUES ('N_0_3_xxx')
INSERT INTO @t (CODE_VD)VALUES ('N_121_131_xxx')
INSERT INTO @t (CODE_VD)VALUES ('N_100_120_xxx')


;WITH
  sorted
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(CODE_VD,3, CHARINDEX('_',CODE_VD, 3)-3) ORDER BY CODE_VD) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    @t
)
SELECT
  CODE_VD
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```